# regexpression for Searching multiline HTML or Xml comments which i can use in bat file

Tags: html, xml, batch-file, comments, multiline

### input file

```
< !--You are a good boy -->    
This is my second line    
<! --I am a good boy
He is hero-->
This is a fine
< !--This line contains xml tags
This can be a html line or xml line    
-->
Done
```

After applying regexp logic in batch file output should be

### output

```
This is my second line
This is a fine
Done
```

Note
---- `< !--` starting of a html or xml comment `-->` stands for ending of a html or xml comment

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Grab some tutorial on regex, or **better yet on DOM parsing**, and then come back , show us your attempts to solve the problem, and ask us some specific questions. We'll be glad to help you.

Comment: I have already gone through the tutorial on regex and made one expression which is working for single line but not working for multiline comments..
.*<!--([.*-->]|([\n.*]))*(-->)*.*

Comment: Edit your Question and post your code and the results you're getting..

Comment: I have already posted my findings.... I have used below regexp for solving this problem bt i think it needs some modification to perform the same.
.*<!--([.*-->]|([\n.*]))*(-->)*.*

Comment: Your comment start should be `<!--`. Comments do not start with `< !--` or `<! --`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little contrived but this will work to get rid of the lines you don't want, including the line which is html or xml.

```
findstr /v "< >" "file.xml"
```

It gives this output: and will remove the html line too with markup code.

```
This is my second line
This is a fine
This can be a html line or xml line
Done
```

Comment: Thnks for suggestion dude but neither it will work nor its working.

Comment: What does it give you with your data?

Comment: Its not working dude..or mainly i have to ignore all the tags that comes under commented block and tags also start from < and end with > so its will not work . but here its not possible to paste data with xml tags n comment its give error n did not allow to upload on the page ..I tried ur solution its printing nothing..blank in another file.

Comment: Supply a download link for the file and what you need in another file.  Put them both in a zip file.